# Database value insertion Error

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, database

How can i manually insert values if not exist...i tried following code but it produce error.How can i insert values if not exist in the table

```
 String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admin " +
                    "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                    " user_name VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " password VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " isAdmin BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', " + 
                    " memo VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))"; 
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);

            String insert="INSERT INTO admin IF NOT EXISTS(id,user_name,password,isAdmin,memo)VALUES(1,'admin','admin',1,'memo')";
            stmt.executeUpdate(insert);
```

it produce an error like

```
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(id,user_name,password,isAdmin,memo)VALUES(1,'admin','admin',1,'mem' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 String insert="INSERT INTO admin IF NOT EXISTS(id,user_name,password,isAdmin,memo)VALUES(1,'admin','admin',1,'memo')";
```

should be

```
 String insert="INSERT IGNORE INTO admin (id,user_name,password,isAdmin,memo)VALUES(1,'admin','admin',1,'memo')";
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (and any other SQL implementation as well) doesn't support `IF NOT EXISTS` in `INSERT` queries.

your `INSERT` query must be

```
"INSERT IGNORE INTO admin (id,user_name,password,isAdmin,memo) VALUES (1,'admin','admin',1,'memo')"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want may be [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) or [INSERT IGNORE...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

The former will update an existing row if a duplicate insert is detected, while the latter will just throw away duplicate inserts.

In both cases, you'll have to create a UNIQUE constraint on the column you want to check for duplicates. If the UNIQUE is violated, the alternate function is invoked.